# Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 “No value.” UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No value.}

Tags: ios, json, nsdata

I'm learning JSON. I have problem with parsing JSON from URL. The error is "Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No value." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No value.}"

JSON is valid - I've checked. This is structure of JSON:

```
[{"id":33,"name":"5","sort":2},{"id":34,"name":"6","sort":3},{"id":35,"name":"7","sortOrder":4}]
```

And this is my code:
    import UIKit

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let urlAsString = "http://www.url.address/"
    let url = NSURL(string: urlAsString)!
    let urlSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let username = "admin"
    let password = "admin"

    struct Address {

        let name: String?
        let id: String?
        let sortOrder: String?

        init(dict: [String: AnyObject]) {

            name = dict["name"] as? String
            id = dict["id"] as? String
            sortOrder = dict["sort"] as? String
        }
    }
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("sections", ofType: "json")
    let jsonData = NSData()

    do {
        if let jsonDic = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData,
            options: .MutableContainers) as? [String: AnyObject] {

                let addr = Address(dict: jsonDic)                    
                print("jsonDic")
        }

        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }
}
func backButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {})
}
```

}

Comment: `jsonData` is an empty `NSData` object. What do you expect? - Joking aside you have to get the data from the `path`

Comment: ... and declare model structs at least on the top level of the class rather than in a method

Answer (score 0):

You need to *actually* use the data from the file:

`guard let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("sections", ofType: "json"),
            let jsonData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path) else {
                fatalError("Cannot find or load the sections file in the main bundle")
        }
do {
        if let sections = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData,
            options: .MutableContainers) as? [String: AnyObject] {
        // work with sections
    }
...`

Comment: Thx. But now I have error  “Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)” with code "fatalError("error")". Mayby because there is no path "sections"? My JSON has no path - only strings as I've mentioned in first question.

Comment: I looks like the problem is with NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("sections", ofType: "json") - how should I change NSBundle if there is no path "sections"? If i leve it empty - pathForResource("", ofType: "json"), problem is the same...

Comment: @Szekspir a simple fix then is to rename your file to `sections.json` (if you want it to be just `json` the you need `pathForResource("json", ofType:"")`.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't rename JSON. So I suppose I should change NSData to NSString. But then I'm getting Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840.